# Typescript with node.js giving "is not a constructor" error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I have a node.js application with two typescript files. 
matchmanager.ts is defined as -

```
namespace LobbyService
{
    export class MatchManager 
    {
    constructor() { /*code*/ }
    }
}
```

and main.ts which is defined as

```
namespace LobbyService
{
    let matchManager: MatchManager = new MatchManager() ;
    /* code */
}
```

I setup visual studio to output the files into a single JS file called lobbyservice.js

However, when i type

```
node lobbyservice.js
```

I get the following error -

```
TypeError: LobbyService.MatchManager is not a constructor
```

The generated file has this output -

```
var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var matchManager = new LobbyService.MatchManager();
})(LobbyService || (LobbyService = {}));
var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var MatchManager = (function () {
        function MatchManager() {
            console.log("created");
        }
        return MatchManager;
    }());
    LobbyService.MatchManager = MatchManager;
})(LobbyService || (LobbyService = {}));
```

This was working before, but for some odd reason it isn't now. Any thoughts?

Update - I managed to get a version of the lobbyservice.js that works. For some odd reason, Visual studio transforms one version of the file into the one above, and one into this -

```
var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var MatchManager = (function () {
        function MatchManager() {
            console.log("created");
        }
        return MatchManager;
    }());
    LobbyService.MatchManager = MatchManager;
})(LobbyService || (LobbyService = {}));
var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var matchManager = new LobbyService.MatchManager();
})(LobbyService || (LobbyService = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=lobby.js.map
```

No clue as to why i'm getting two different outputs like that for the same source code. Both projects have the same module property of "none"

Comment: any reason why you are using namespaces? You should just use require in order to import other modules.

Comment: What does the compiled output look like?

Comment: Compiled output looks like this -
var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var matchManager = new LobbyService.MatchManager();

// ....

var LobbyService;
(function (LobbyService) {
    var MatchManager = (function () {

Comment: I'm using namespaces to keep things ordely - have quite a few different code libraries around. The weird thing is that this WAS working before, with no imports needed

Comment: To help, i edited the article with a smple of the generated code

Comment: The problem is that your files are concatenated in the wrong order: `main.ts`  and then `matchmanager.ts`, when what you want is `matchmanager.ts` and then`main.ts`. Maybe look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So user Elliott highlighted that indeed it's a know typescript compile quirk where the order of the output javascript file creates an issue.

to fix that, i had to add

```
/// <reference path="matchmanager.ts"/>
```

On my typescript files that used MatchManager class, even though they were on the same namespace and compiled ok. This forced the typescript compiler to create a workable javascript output.